# How to return counts even when no records found in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hope you can help me out with this query I'm struggling with.  Currently I have the following SQL which works fine but I want to include the end_date column as well, but still return values even if SYSDATE() <= end_date.  Here is the query without the end_date condition and the results:

```
SELECT pkgCnt.holiday_type_desc, COUNT(DISTINCT pkgCnt.package_heading) AS count
FROM package pkg,
(
    SELECT pkg.holiday_type_id, holiday_type_desc, package_heading
    FROM package pkg
    INNER JOIN holiday_type ht ON pkg.holiday_type_id = ht.holiday_type_id
    GROUP BY pkg.holiday_type_id, package_heading
) AS pkgCnt
INNER JOIN holiday_type ht ON pkgCnt.holiday_type_id = ht.holiday_type_id
WHERE pkg.package_heading = pkgCnt.package_heading
GROUP BY pkg.holiday_type_id
ORDER BY pkg.holiday_type_id;
```

And the results are the following which is perfect:

```
holiday_type_desc   count
Bush Breaks         6
City Breaks         5
Golf Breaks         1
Adventure Holidays  3
Beach Holidays      5
Family Holidays     1
```

But when I add the end_date as shown by the query below the result is empty:

```
SELECT pkgCnt.holiday_type_desc, COUNT(DISTINCT pkgCnt.package_heading) AS count
FROM package pkg,
(
    SELECT pkg.holiday_type_id, holiday_type_desc, package_heading
    FROM package pkg
    INNER JOIN holiday_type ht ON pkg.holiday_type_id = ht.holiday_type_id
    GROUP BY pkg.holiday_type_id, package_heading
) AS pkgCnt
INNER JOIN holiday_type ht ON pkgCnt.holiday_type_id = ht.holiday_type_id
WHERE pkg.package_heading = pkgCnt.package_heading
AND SYSDATE() <= pkg.end_date
GROUP BY pkg.holiday_type_id
ORDER BY pkg.holiday_type_id;
```

But I would like for the query to return the following:

```
holiday_type_desc   count
Bush Breaks         0
City Breaks         0
Golf Breaks         0
Adventure Holidays  0
Beach Holidays      0
Family Holidays     0
```

Comment: Use `Left Join` Instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @JaydipJ I've tried LEFT JOIN as well without the desired effect.

Comment: in your this query you could use `right join` because you want to select everything from your sub-query (PKGCNT)

Comment: Do conditional count in the select-list (using a case expression.)'

Comment: Yes @Jarth .. the same approach came in my mind and I posted .. 
This should be satisfactory for the expectation ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this also -

```
SELECT pkgCnt.holiday_type_desc,
         COUNT(DISTINCT pkgCnt.package_heading) AS count,
         sum(case
               when SYSDATE() <= pkg.end_date then
                1
               else
                0
             end) as count_after_codition
    FROM package pkg,
         (SELECT pkg.holiday_type_id, holiday_type_desc, package_heading
            FROM package pkg
           INNER JOIN holiday_type ht
              ON pkg.holiday_type_id = ht.holiday_type_id
           GROUP BY pkg.holiday_type_id, package_heading) AS pkgCnt
   INNER JOIN holiday_type ht
      ON pkgCnt.holiday_type_id = ht.holiday_type_id
   WHERE pkg.package_heading = pkgCnt.package_heading
   GROUP BY pkg.holiday_type_id
   ORDER BY pkg.holiday_type_id;
```

Comment: @pratik_garg this is much closer to what I'm looking for, thanks very much.

Comment: If it is satisfactory then you can mark this as an answer .. otherwise if you still have some difficulties to get your expectation .. you can post here..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pratik garg I managed to come up with the solution I was looking for.  Please find the final SQL below:

```
SELECT pkgCnt.holiday_type_desc,
    CASE
        WHEN SYSDATE() <= pkg.end_date THEN
            COUNT(DISTINCT pkgCnt.package_heading)
        ELSE
            0
    END count
FROM package pkg,
(
    SELECT pkg.holiday_type_id, holiday_type_desc, package_heading
    FROM package pkg
    INNER JOIN holiday_type ht
    ON pkg.holiday_type_id = ht.holiday_type_id
    GROUP BY pkg.holiday_type_id, package_heading
) AS pkgCnt INNER JOIN holiday_type ht ON pkgCnt.holiday_type_id = ht.holiday_type_id
WHERE pkg.package_heading = pkgCnt.package_heading
GROUP BY pkg.holiday_type_id
ORDER BY pkg.holiday_type_id;
```